# Reasoner sets two different classes equivalent to each other and owl:Thing

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege, turtle-rdf, hermit

I am working on an ontology for video games for an university course project, specifically focused on the relations between different genres. I have included [this](http://vocab.linkeddata.es/vgo/) ontology in my project and expanded on it. The current state of the OWL document is [here](https://gist.github.com/pero5ar/0482ed9a3dd2ddc7c444e890115e4c1c).

When I start the HermiT reasoner in Protégé, it states that `Game` is `Equivalent To Genre` with the explanations:

[image: Game Equivalent To Genre explanation]

Furthermore, it states that `owl:Thing` is `Equivalent To Game` and equivalent to `Genre` with the following explanations (respectively):

[image: owl:Thing Equivalent To Game explanation]

[image: owl:Thing Equivalent To Genre explanation]

As you may suppose, this is definitely not a result that I expected. I have tried setting `Game Disjoint With Genre`, but the reasoner then states that the ontology is inconsistent. The explanation it gives is the same as the explanation for `Game Equivalent To Genre` but with the added `Disjoint With` restriction in each explanation.

This is my first time working with something like this, so I would be grateful if someone can explain to me the fallacy in my logic. What causes this behavior, why, and how can I fix it?

In addition, here is the code of the two object properties that seem to cause the trouble (the rest can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/pero5ar/0482ed9a3dd2ddc7c444e890115e4c1c)):

```
###  http://example.org/VideoGameOntologyExtended#hasElementsOf
:hasElementsOf rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
                        owl:ReflexiveProperty ;
               rdfs:domain vgo:Genre ;
               rdfs:range vgo:Genre .

###  http://example.org/VideoGameOntologyExtended#isSimilarTo
:isSimilarTo rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
                      owl:SymmetricProperty ,
                      owl:ReflexiveProperty ;
             rdfs:domain vgo:Game ;
             rdfs:range vgo:Game .
```

Comment: Isn't this obvious? I mean, in all explanations the reflexivity axioms occur. Do you really need the reflexivity? To understand the entailment better, `p` beeing reflexive is a shortcut for `owl:Thing SubClassOf p some Self` and the range `C` of `p` means `owl:Thing SubClassOf p only C`

Comment: The project assignment states that I have to have at least one example of using `owl:ReflexiveProperty`. The course materials do not explain the property, and the course primarily deals with databases and not semantic web. The definitions I found online gave me the impression that a reflexive property just means that an instance of a class that has that property (i.e. class that is the domain of the property), automatically has itself "on both sides" of the property.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Reflexive_Object_Properties) then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give you a hint for the entailment `owl:Thing EquivalentTo Game`:

We have

`Reflexive: isSimilarTo`

which is equivalent to

`owl:Thing SubClassOf isSimilarTo some Self`

which in fact means each individual in your ontology is related to itself via the property `isSimilarTo`, i.e. for each individual `x` in your ontology we can entail

`isSimilarTo(x, x)`

In addition, we have

`isSimilarTo Range Game`

which is semantically equivalent to the axiom

`owl:Thing SubClassOf isSimilarTo only Game`

This means, if there is such a relation `isSimilarTo(x, y)`, the object `y` will belong to class `Game`.

Now, remember that we already said that every individual in the ontology has such a relation, just to itself. Thus, we can infer that each individual belongs to class `Game`.

Comment: so, if I understand correctly, if I want to use `owl:ReflexiveProperty` I should not define the domain and range of `isSimilarTo`, otherwise that class will be equivalent to `owl:Thing`, because domain and range are not restrictions on a property, but used as assertions that any individual on the domain or range side of a property is an instance of the class defined as domain or range, and reflexivity implies that a relation of an individual to itself exists for all individuals (regardless of type)?

Comment: That is correct. And don't worry, *domain* and *range* are quite often misunderstood in the OWL context. And yes, using `Reflexive: p` means *global reflexivity*, that is, the property holds for all individuals

Comment: Thank you, things make a lot more sense now :) I suppose then that properties cannot be restricted to be used only by certain classes in any way?

Comment: Not really, OWL is more about inferring statements or in the worst case, as you already discovered, inconsistency. In contrast to databases, in OWL you'' also have to live with the *Open World Assumption*, i.e. missing information can't be considered as *false*.  There are some initiatives/languages on top of RDF like SHACL to define proper constraints. Maybe you can have a look at those.